# Can't re-register same token to Azure push notification server after it's deleted?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I'm registering client devices to the Azure Notification Hub, within Android, and it works well. Push notifications work and everything is stable.

Until I forcefully delete the registration directly within the Azure Push Notification Hub. After that when the app tries to re-register using the same Firebase Token, it doesn't get re-added back into the notification hub.

Is this by design? How should I handle this situation, if the registration server forgets registrations?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not by design. Are you still seeing the issue? If so, we can better help you if you open up an Azure support ticket which will allow us to dig through logs.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, still seeing the issue. How do I create a support ticket? I'd need a support plan for that I'm guessing?

Comment: You should be able to do it in Azure Portal.
1. Navigate to your hub experiencing the issue.
2. In the side panel, you should see a `Support + troubleshooting` section.